# как обратиться к вложенной функции?

Tags: javascript, замыкания

```
function asdf() {
    function dsa() {
        alert(123);
    }
}
```

как обратиться к функции dsa?

Comment: _как обратиться к функции dsa?_, извне `asdf` никак

Answer (score 5):

Любая функция (включая "стрелочные") создает свой scope (область видимости). Поэтому, ровно как извне функции `asdf()` нельзя обратиться к переменным, объявленным внутри этой функции, так нельзя и к другим функциям, объявленным внутри этой.

Однако, если внешняя функция **возвращает** вложенную, то обратиться к ней не составит труда:

```
function asdf() {
    return function asd() {
    }
}

asdf()();
```

Comment: Стрелочные тоже создают свой скоуп.

Answer (score 2):

Гулять - так гулять.

```js
function asdf() {
  function dsa() {
    console.log('from dsa: 123');
  }
  console.log('from adsf: old code');
}

var strAsdf = asdf.toString();
var startIndex = strAsdf.indexOf("{");
var strAsdf = strAsdf.substring(0, startIndex + 1) +
  "if (arguments[0] === 'getMeDsa') return dsa;" +
  strAsdf.substring(startIndex + 1);
eval(strAsdf);

asdf('getMeDsa')();
asdf();
```

Comment: возможно ли обратиться вне функции asdf?

Comment: @green "Сделаем функцию `dsa` локальной, видимой только внутри функции `asdf`. А теперь начнем искать способ вызвать `dsa` из кода, который находится вне `asdf`." - не проще ли не создавать искусственные трудности и изначально сделать `dsa` видимой для всех?

Comment: проще, но нужно сделать костыль) спасибо за ответ

Comment: Боже... Зовите экзорцистов :D

Comment: @smellyshovel - осиновые колья предоставляются

Comment: ето конечно дичь еще та, но мне понравилось :)

Comment: Плохое решение, если `dsa` будет использовать переменные объявленные в `asdf`

Comment: вот это круто))

Comment: @Grundy "если то, если сё", мне что, обязательно смайлик надо в ответ вставить?

Comment: @Igor, от смайлика решение не станет хорошим

Comment: @Grundy у Вас сегодня день занудства?

Comment: @Grundy, моя очередь занудствовать. _"если dsa будет использовать переменные объявленные в asdf"_, то всё будет хорошо :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, да,я уже увидел, что он кроваво патчит основную функцию, и вот если бы она принимала параметры, то все было бы печально :-)

Comment: @Grundy, снова мимо. Первый раз было ближе)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, все в точку, если уже есть параметр, то он на него просто забивает

Comment: @Grundy, в примеру функция без параметров. Если бы была с параметрами, можно было бы всегда добавить ещё один в конец. А ещё передавать туда Symbol, чтобы уж точно ни с чем не совпал.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну мало ли, что в примере без параметров, это ни о чем не говорит

Answer (score -2):

Как вариант, но подойдёт ли он в вашем случае, не знаю.

```
function asdf() {
  this.dsa = function() {
    alert(123);
  }
}

 let Asdf = new asdf();
 Asdf.dsa();
```

Comment: Да ну? Запусти.

Comment: @Qwertiy 
`% node code.js`
`123`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp9p9.png

Comment: @Qwertiy я скопировал случайно из вопроса код, поправил уже.